# Export Access Database to text File Java

Tags: java, ms-access, text

I am trying to create text file from Select * of access mdb file, I wrote below code to implement same, but while I am trying to read the data I am getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid descriptor index"

Not sure if this method will actually work, here's the code:

```
//=============Extract contents in Access and save it as Text File Format==========================================
//String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\test\\TestEJFolder\\BWC_Ejournal.mdb";
String connectionString ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=C:\\test\\TestEJFolder\\BWC_Ejournal.mdb;";
DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, "", "");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, "", "");
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Events";
Statement cmd = conn.createStatement(); 
cmd.execute(sql);
ResultSet reader = cmd.executeQuery(sql);
//String path = "\\" + time_stmp + "_" + file_name;
File sw = new File(text_dir,file_name);
File ssw = new File(s_path);
sw.createNewFile();     
final String format = "{0,-22} {1,-4} {2,-4} {3,-4} {4,-20} {5,-22}";
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sw));
String line = null;
//reader.beforeFirst();
//boolean b = true;
int colCount = rs.getColumnCount();
while (reader.next())
{
    //Errors here while trying to read      
    line = String.format(format, String.format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}", reader.getObject(5)).trim(), reader.getObject(0).toString().trim(), reader.getObject(1).toString().trim(), reader.getObject(2).toString().trim(), reader.getObject(3).toString().trim(), reader.getObject(4).toString().trim());
}
output.write(line);
output.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace. Also, you are expected to post only relevant code here

Comment: Check if the resultset is read correctly.

Comment: Here's the complete trace: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid descriptor index
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLColAttributes(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getColAttribute(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getColumnType(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getObject(Unknown Source)
 at CopyEJ.CopyEJ.main(CopyEJ.java:161)

Comment: You can edit your question. Please remove all of the irrelevant code, post stack trace and highlight the line throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from your code:

```
...reader.getObject(0).toString().trim()
```

AFAICT, you are expected to pass column index starting from 1 to `getObject` method. I'm not sure what are you trying to get there.

P.S. Next time pay attention to code formatting (remove all of the empty lines, comments, unnecessary statements), post stack trace and highlight clearly the line throwing an exception.

Comment: as soon I start index from 1, there is no error but only formatting is written to the text file . Here's output {0,-22} {1,-4} {2,-4} {3,-4} {4,-20} {5,-22}, Do i need to run this through count of columns in loop to display all data ?

Comment: @user2385057 You can output the value of each column. (`reader.getObject(index).toString()`). Then you can figure out whether the problem is with formatting, data, query or resultset

Comment: if I use following :line =   reader.getObject(6).toString().trim()+ reader.getObject(1).toString().trim()+ reader.getObject(2).toString().trim()+ reader.getObject(3).toString().trim()+ reader.getObject(4).toString().trim()+ reader.getObject(5).toString().trim();     it returns me only the last column in data

Comment: @user2385057 Actually what are you trying to achieve with format string like this?

Comment: @user2385057 You're outputting only last row in data. Move `output.write(line)` inside the loop

Comment: ohh right .. btw adding a linebreak also helped me to organize the data better .. line =   reader.getObject(6).toString().trim()+ reader.getObject(1).toString().trim()+ reader.getObject(2).toString().trim()+ reader.getObject(3).toString().trim()+ reader.getObject(4).toString().trim()+ reader.getObject(5).toString().trim() + linebreak; I am trying out more formatting options here .. thnks!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem at the `String.format`.  Check out [Java Tutorial on Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html):

> #### Creating Format Strings
>
> You have seen the use of the `printf()` and `format()` methods to print output with formatted numbers. The `String` class has an equivalent class method, `format()`, that returns a `String` object rather than a `PrintStream` object.
>
> Using `String`'s static `format()` method allows you to create a formatted string that you can reuse, as opposed to a one-time print statement. For example, instead of
>
> ```
> System.out.printf("The value of the float " +
>                   "variable is %f, while " +
>                   "the value of the " + 
>                   "integer variable is %d, " +
>                   "and the string is %s", 
>                   floatVar, intVar, stringVar);
> ```
>
> you can write
>
> ```
> String fs;
> fs = String.format("The value of the float " +
>                    "variable is %f, while " +
>                    "the value of the " + 
>                    "integer variable is %d, " +
>                    " and the string is %s",
>                    floatVar, intVar, stringVar);
> System.out.println(fs);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to separate the test to a small unit of function

1.1 read from DB into object(if you have the time try to use hibernate)
1.2 try to print the object
1.3 try to write to file

see that every unit

i see some problems :
1.the Date should be Date object and not String
2.you have more then one connection

Comment: what could be a problem with more than one connection ? because I am closing them as soon I am done deriving the functionality

Comment: Try to organize your code one method for one action i see getColumnType i think it is because of the Date